# establishing DHCP's setting up OSPF, and loopbacks in a small network with a switch

Tags: networking, cisco, dhcp, ospf

im attempting to do an assignment for my class, it requires setting up 3 routers connected to a switch, 2 laptops that must receive IP's through DHCP of a specific type, then setting up loopbacks, and dividing the areas into zones for OSPF, and be able to ping the laptops on each network, my problems seems to stem from a failure to properly establish the DHCP's, i believe everything else seems to be within my grasp except the base configuration of the network

i rewrite the DHCP's time and time again, however i cant seem to make them line up properly the instructions require a CR of /25 however the ip's im supposed to use say that is a bad mask for thier IP's, aswel, i am having issues ensuring that the DHCP's are set up properly, as i think their is something small im not doing correctly, but im not sure where to look for the issue.